# Filtering a dataframe by a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

Dataframe:

```
Date           Name       Value     Rank       Mean
01/02/2019     A           10       100        8.2
02/03/2019     A           9        120        7.9
01/03/2019     B           3        40         6.4
03/02/2019     B           1        39         5.9
...
```

And following list:

```
date=['01/02/2019','03/02/2019'...]
```

I would like to filter the df by the list, but as a date range, so for each value in the list I would like to bring back data between the date and the date-30 days

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide any code examples that you're having trouble with in tackling your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `numpy` broadcast here, notice this method is o(n*m) , which mean if both of the df and date list is huge , it will exceed the memory limit

```
s=pd.to_datetime(date).values
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
s1=df.Date.values
t=(s-s1[:,None]).astype('timedelta64[D]').astype(int)
df[np.any((t>=0)&(t<=30),1)]
Out[120]: 
        Date Name  Value  Rank  Mean
0 2019-01-02    A     10   100   8.2
1 2019-02-03    A      9   120   7.9
3 2019-03-02    B      1    39   5.9
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date is a string, just do:

```
df[df.date.isin(list_of_dates)]
```